# foreach loop issue

Tags: asp.net

branch is of checkbox list type, but while looping through this it adds only one item while i want to store all "li" in branch_id and want to retrive later why it's not adding all in branch_is. is there any other option which can add all this to variable branch_id.

```
          foreach (ListItem li in branch.Items) 
                {
                    if(li.Selected)
                    {

                        List<int> branch_id = new List<int>();
                        branch_id.Add(Convert.ToInt32(li.Value));

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
List<int> branch_id = new List<int>();
foreach (ListItem li in branch.Items) 
{
     if(li.Selected)
     {
          branch_id.Add(Convert.ToInt32(li.Value));
     }
}
```

Or this one if you are using .Net 3.5 or higher and can use LINQ

```
List<int> branch_id = branch.Items.Where(li=>li.Selected).Select(li=>li.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: oh my god every time a new object was creating that's y

Answer (score 0):

you no need for initializing the  `List<int> branch_id = new List<int>();` again.

If you initialize it will  create a new instance for the branch_id  and clear all the present value.

```
foreach (ListItem li in branch.Items) 
                {
                    if(li.Selected)
                    {

                        List<int> branch_id = new List<int>(); // during each time it loops it create new memory and you can't save all the values
                        branch_id.Add(Convert.ToInt32(li.Value));

                    }
                }



so do 

List<int> branch_id = new List<int>(); 
foreach (ListItem li in branch.Items) 
                {
                    if(li.Selected)
                    {


                        branch_id.Add(Convert.ToInt32(li.Value));

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I once [wrote about an extension method](http://www.notesoncode.com/articles/2009/03/03/PowerfulExtensionMethodsPart3.aspx) that allows me to simplify the selection with LINQ:

```
var branch_id = branch.Items.WhereSelected().Select(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.Value)).ToList()
```

Comment: i am using 2.o thats y it doesn't work in that i think.
Well yours answer is of a great help as well.
thanks